# Is there a way around being required to use GoDaddy as the registrar when using a custom domain with Microsoft 365 Family?

Tags: office365, domain, registrar

I want to use my own domain with my Microsoft 365 Family plan, but there is no way I am transferring it to GoDaddy. Is there way way around this “requirement” or am I stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the article
[Get a personalized email address in Microsoft 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-personalized-email-address-in-microsoft-365-75416a58-b225-4c02-8c07-8979403b427b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us):

> **Q:** I already own a domain that's registered with a provider other than GoDaddy. Can I set up a personalized email address in
> Outlook.com?
>
> **A:** At the moment, we only support connecting domains managed by GoDaddy with Outlook.com.

When entering my Premium subscription, I can see the following in Manage my subscription:

---

[image]

---

The answer is then : Not possible at the moment.
I have no information if this will change in the future.

Comment: It is possible, I have just done it with a name on Namecheap per [this support thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/i-have-m365-family-and-a-domain-name-not-on/09bdfb09-e1cb-4098-b260-c3b245194f61) which also matches the Reddit answer below.

Answer (score 22):

This related Reddit discussion indicates that it's possible and working at the time.  It involves pretending to go to GoDaddy, and then capturing key values from the outlink for manual DNS updating.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/ft15pk/use_personalized_domain_with_outlook_and_office/

---

> 1. Go to outlook, the premium settings and choose the option to "get started" with a personalized domain.
> 2. Click the option to buy a new domain with GoDaddy, and a new window opens
> 3. Copy the URL of the new window that opens, it should look like this:
>    https://domainconnect.godaddy.com/v2/domainTemplates/providers/outlook.com/services/personalizedoutlookemail/apply?mxRecordValue=XXXXXXXXX&state=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>
>    The part that you need is "mxRecordValue=XXXXXXXXX"
>
>    **The XXXXXXXXX is the unique ID for verification used in DNS**
> 4. Go to your own domain DNS settings and add the following settings replacing XXXXXXXXX with your ID found in step 3.
>
>    **The dot on the end of the external domains is not a typo!**
>
> | Name | TTL | Type | Value | Priority |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | @ | 1 hour | MX | **XXXXXXXXX**.pamx1.hotmail.com. | 0 |
> | @ | 1 hour | TXT | v=spf1 | include:outlook.com -all |  |
> | autodiscover | 1 hour | CNAME | autodiscover.outlook.com. |  |
> | _dmarc | 1 hour | TXT | v=DMARC1; p=none; |  |
> | _domainconnect | 1 hour | CNAME | _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com. |  |
> | _outlook | 1 hour | TXT | **XXXXXXXXX** |  |

> 5. Return to the premium settings in outlook to set your custom domain.
> 6. Choose the option "I already have a domain"
> 7. Enter the domain you just configured
> 8. You have to click to login to GoDaddy, do this, but just exit the page it goes to.
> 9. Congratulations it should now say you connected the domain with GoDaddy!

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: I just used this today (2/2/22) to connect a domain I have registered at Namecheap and it worked great.  After I added the DNS records below, I had to wait about 30 minutes before step 7/8 would work.  It probably just took some time for the DNS changes to propagate or something like that.

Afterward, I went to Outlook Settings > Mail > "Sync email" and set my default "From address".

If Outlook didn't automatically add the alias you want (it added {first_name}@{domain} by default for me), go to Outlook Settings > Premium > Personalized Email Address page to add it.

Comment: Just tried this (2022-02-05) - didn't work. Registrar is Google, and DNS forces the `_domainconnect` CNAME to point at Google. No way that i can see to edit or replace it. Trying to set a custom CNAME just gets rejected. Booo Microsoft, booo Google.

Comment: 2022-04-12 This worked perfectly! Registrar is a smaller one, but it makes sense that the bigger ones like Google as mentioned by @cautionbug might not allow it

Comment: Important to note that the MX record priority *must* be 0.

Comment: 2022-09-17 This worked! Namecheap was registrar and it took a half hour for settings to propagate.

Comment: Worked with Route53

Answer (score 1):

Not according to Microsoft.

In their FAQ for personal and family subscriptions ([Get a personalised address in Microsoft 365](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/get-a-personalized-email-address-in-microsoft-365-75416a58-b225-4c02-8c07-8979403b427b)) is this question:

> I already own a domain that's registered with a provider other than GoDaddy. Can I set up a personalized email address in Outlook.com?

Their answer is:

> At the moment, we only support connecting domains managed by GoDaddy with Outlook.com

Business and enterprise plans allow other registrars - see this MS doc [Buy a domain name](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-with-domains/buy-a-domain-name?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: @Giacomo1968 - they were posted one minute apart, I guess we were checking the same document at the same time.

Comment: An answer submitted 1 minute apart isn’t considered to be an earlier answer